# logical_not used for 1,0 rather than True, False in boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, logical-operators

I want to get the inverse of all components in an array containing a certain number of `0` and `1`.
When I use `numpy.logical_not` it returns `False` and `True` instead:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,0,0])
b=np.logical_not(a)
print b
```

will return `[False,True,True]` rather than `[0,1,1]` (which is what I would like to get). Of course, I can manually create a function that transforms the `False` back to `0` and the `True` back to `1`, but is there a more direct way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1 - a
```

Just use arithmetic operators instead of logical operators.